# How do I implement form handling when form is custom HTML?

Tags: forms

I am new to WP and back-end in general. I want to make a site with multiple forms and I am curios how and where do I handle them ?

One of those forms is a form inside footer in which the user is supposed to input its email address in order to subscribe to a newsletter.

The footer is added via custom html and the form inside it looks like this:

```
        <form action="" method="post">
          <input
            type="email"
            name=""
            id=""
            placeholder="Enter your e-mail address"
          />
          <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
```

I've linked the WP site to a database and, as such, I would like to store the inputted emails into a table. How can I do that ? I am not proficient in PHP, but I don't think it's that hard to search up how to handle email forms.

The problem is that I have no idea where to write the code. I am used to creating ExpressJS handlers, but with WP I have no idea what to do.

Also, do form plugins handle the back-end as well ? Or are they only front-end elements ? And if they also handle the back-end, what plugin would you recommend for a multi-form that takes into account every choice of the user and then redirects him to the proper page/product ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you point me to some docs or an article, guide, tutorial ? Because I have no idea how to implement what you've just said.

Comment: @ChrisNorman That's not much to go on. Can you please think of something more ?

Comment: Do I put the code in the custom html ?

Comment: I modified my comments into an answer for you.

Comment: How do I add then to my website ? Do I remove it from the Custom HTML and put it only in the code you've provided ? And if I remove it from the Custom HTML won't that mess up the whole design ?

Comment: A plugin adds additional code or functionality into WordPress. You will still need to add CSS for the form to 'look good', and positioned where you want it too. Done right, you will not mess up the whole design - a plugin is the preferred method for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Forms can handle both the front end and back end. If you don't code the forms correctly, there can be some huge security issues that will arise. With what you are talking about, you will have to use a WordPress hook something like this:

`function your_function() {     //your form here } add_action( 'wp_footer', 'your_function' );`

This will put your form in the footer on the page. You will want to put your code in a custom plugin - so that the user can add it to his/her site.

In order to do this, here are some references to point you in the right direction.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_footer
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro
https://www.sitepoint.com/build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-plugin-in-5-minutes/

The tutorial from sitepoint should get you started. The tutorial goes through some plugin building and creating a form. After you have that - just implement the code

`function your_function() {     //your form here } add_action( 'wp_footer', 'your_function' );`

Code reference: developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_footer

Now regarding your other question about database tables - that a whole other beast. Here is the documentation for that: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

Depending on your level of coding experience - you may want to just find an over-the-counter plugin to handle this. There is a reason WPforms and ContactForms7 are widely used - it takes a lot of work to create a plugin that will handle forms well.